# Error when trying to connect to SQL Server from program on remote computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to set up a system for employees to use in the office so they can run certain programs from a website.

They will be able to login and go to a reports page an click a button to run a reports program on the utility server. The program will connect to SQL Server to get the login information and then login to another site and programmatically create the reports and download them.

If I run the program as a stand alone program on the server it runs fine. I even have it running as a scheduled task on the server itself and it runs fine. It is only when I try to run the program from the website that I get the error stating the program but it is terminated due to an unhandled exception. Here is the stack trace from the error in the event viewer.

> Application: Trending Reports.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> Stack:
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>          at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>          at Trending_Reports.Program.Main(System.String[])

Here is the code I am using to start the program.

```
var processToRun = new[] { @"D:\test\Trending Reports.exe" };

var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connection.Username = "Username";
connection.Password = "password";

var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", "Server"), connection);
wmiScope.Connect();

var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
```

The program itself is using multi-threading. Could this be causing the issue? Or could it be a user issue to where its not using my user profile on the remote computer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the SQL server to accept remote connections? This is a common cause for errors.

You can follow the following steps:

- Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want
  to connect to from a remote computer.
- Configure SQL server to listen on static port
- Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.
- Configure the firewall to allow network traffic that is related to
  SQL Server and to the SQL Server Browser service.

[This](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) link here has a step-by-step tutorial with pictures (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express).

Comment: Yes i did that and most of that was already set up but im still getting the same error.